# Aerospike cluster behavior in different consistency mode?

Tags: aerospike, consistency, data-consistency, aerospike-ce

I want to understand the behavior of aerospike in different consistancy mode.

Consider  a aerospike cluster running with 3 nodes and replication factor 3.

`AP modes is simple and it says`

***Aerospike will allow reads and writes in every sub-cluster.***

`And Maximum no. of node which can go down < 3 (replication factor)`

For  aerospike strong consistency it  says

***Note that the only successful writes are those made on replication-factor number of nodes. Every other write is unsuccessful***

Does this really means the no writes are allowed if available nodes <  replication factor.

And then same document says

***All writes are committed to every replica before the system returns success to the client. In case one of the replica writes fails, the master will ensure that the write is completed to the appropriate number of replicas within the cluster (or sub cluster in case the system has been compromised.)***

what does `appropriate number of replica means` ?

So if I lose one node from my 3 node cluster with strong consistency and replication factor 3 , I will not be able to wright data ?

Answer (score 3):

> For aerospike strong consistency it says
>
> Note that the only successful writes are those made on
>   replication-factor number of nodes. Every other write is unsuccessful
>
> Does this really means the no writes are allowed if available nodes <
>   replication factor.

Yes, if there are fewer than `replication-factor` nodes then it is impossible to meet the user specified `replication-factor`.

> All writes are committed to every replica before the system returns
>   success to the client. In case one of the replica writes fails, the
>   master will ensure that the write is completed to the appropriate
>   number of replicas within the cluster (or sub cluster in case the
>   system has been compromised.)
>
> what does appropriate number of replica means ?

It means `replication-factor` nodes must receive the write. When a node fails, a new node can be promoted to replica status until either the node returns or an operator registers a new `roster` (cluster membership list).

> So if I lose one node from my 3 node cluster with strong consistency
>   and replication factor 3 , I will not be able to wright data ?

Yes, so having all nodes a replicas wouldn't be a very useful configuration. `Replication-factor` 3 allows up to 2 nodes to be down, but only if the remaining nodes are able to satisfy the `replication-factor`. So for `replication-factor` 3 you would probably want to run with a minimum of 5 nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, with 3 nodes and RF 3, losing one node means the cluster will not be able to successfully take write transactions since it wouldn't be able to write the required number of copies (3 in this case).

Appropriate number of replicas means a number of replicas that would match the replication factor configured.

Comment: In AP mode, 2 nodes can go down in 3 node cluster with RF 3, right ?

Comment: If you were thinking of 3 copies in AP mode as a way to bolster consistency, you should be using RF 2 with strong consistency instead.

Comment: @Abhijit, you are correct. It will reduce RF to 1 in such case. I would go with Ronen's suggestion in general, though (of course that requires an Enterprise License...).